# why doesn't my function return?

Tags: python

I am a total newbie, thus I must apologize for this dumb question. But why doesn't my function return anything??

```
def correct_sentence(some_sent):
    list_of_big = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    list_of_small = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    list_of_sent = list(str(some_sent))
    if list_of_sent[len(list_of_sent)-1] != ".":
        list_of_sent.append(".")
    if list_of_sent[0] in list_of_small:
        for i in range(26):
            if list_of_small[i] == list_of_sent[0]:
                the_index = i
                list_of_sent[0] = list_of_big[the_index]
    new_str = "".join(list_of_sent)
    return new_str
correct_sentence(input())
```

Comment: Put it in code block.. Ctrl+k

Comment: I've edited the question with a better format - but I need someone to approve the edit

Comment: There's a good chance the problem is related to incorrect indentation—e.g., the only `return` is inside an `if` statement it shouldn't be inside, so in all other cases it just falls off the end and returns the default `None`—but that's impossible to see if your pasted code isn't formatted as a code block with the same indentation as your real code.

Comment: What do you mean _it doesn't return anything_? Do you want to display the output of this function? I tried it and it works.

Comment: Cannot confirm. Your function returns the new string. But your code is really messy.

Comment: Are you confusing "printing" and "returning" a value? This seems to be a frequent problem: https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/teaching-students-that-printf-is-not-the-same-as-return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked why your function does not return anything. It does return, actually, you just do not know. To know if it is returning the value, try to print it. So:

```
print(correct_sentence(input())
```

Changing your code to this will make the code print the returned value.

Comment: How is your code different from the OP's code, except that you removed  the harmless `str()`?

Comment: It wasn't. Since `some_sent` is a string, applying `str()` to a string simply returns the same string.

Comment: Well, I do not know why (maybe difference between our python versions) but I had this error: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
` at line 11.

Comment: You must have overwritten your built-in function str() by assigning something else to `str`.

Comment: You are right. How am I supposed to even find it? Cause I know that I did not write a new `str()` function.

Comment: Changing the code to the code in your answer will lead to problems. You don't call `input`.

Answer (score 1):

It does return something, maybe you are wondering why it doesnt print something? To try that you can try to type print(correct_sentence(input())) instead at the end

Comment: but why should I? It is supposed to "return" it to the user, isn't it?

Comment: To display the result, you have to use the `print` function.

Comment: @VasilisG. Not when you call the function from the prompt.

Comment: @Dyz that is correct. I think the OP needs to specify that.

Comment: @AlexandraZhuk:  No, `return` is not supposed to return the data to the user. `return` returns the data to the caller, and the caller is a line of software in your code. It's up to you to write morde code which will print the returned value.

Answer (score -1):

This is not really a direct answer to your question, but here's what you should have done to "correct" a sentence:

```
def correct_sentence(some_sent):
    uppercased = some_sent[0].upper() + some_sent[1:].strip()
    if not uppercased.endswith("."):
        uppercased += "."
    return uppercased
```

(The function acts oddly if a sentence ends with a non-period punctuation, but hopefully you can handle it on your own.)